# Is there an equivalent to boost::multi_index container, that is sorted simultaneously by more than one index?

Tags: sorting, dictionary, indexing, julia

I need to store intermediary calculation results in the memory. The elements must be quick to add and remove by their `ID` field and the container must support quick lookup for the one with the biggest value in the `quality` field.

Internally I would implement it using bindings to [boost::multi_index](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/index.html), but I would prefer to use a native solution.

Implementation would most likely require sorted/hash indices that translate the specified external fields into some internal object ID, and one extra hash map to hold the actual objects accessible by that internal object ID.